# AWS API Gateway and Kinesis integration - No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I am following AWS documentation 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html to get sharditerator using get method of API Gateway by passing stream-name and shard-id as query parameter like - shard-id=shardId-000000000000. But, I am getting this exception:

Response Body

{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}

Logs:

Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 200

I tried enabling CORS but no help.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you post relevant API gateway settings you've used?

Comment: On API Gateway console, go to "Method Responses" section and see if a HTTP Status 200 response is configured. If missing - add it,, deploy the API and test again.